# Change hibernate ValidationMessage.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

i want to change default spring validation message file from ValidationMessage_en.properties to ValidationMessage_fa.properties file
the ValidationMessage_fa.properties still exist in org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages_fa.properties or in detail (.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.2.5.Final/hibernate-validator-6.2.5.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages_fa.properties)
but i dont how to replace that

Comment: "I want to..." is not a question. Also, please format your code and tell us what you tried so far and where you got stuck and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add config item as follow:

```
spring.web.locale=fa
spring.web.locale-resolver=fixed
```